# Reaching SESSIONS and COOKIES From Different Directories

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

For example; i have two directory under www directory like in picture
[image]

If i define a cookie inside for example site1 i can not reach the cookie from site2 directory.
This situation is same for sessions. Is there any way to reaching them from different directories?

Comment: By "reach" it, do you mean the values aren't set? Are they just different directories or different sites too?

Comment: These are different sites with different domains. But each site belong to me.

Answer (score 0):

If the two sites are subdomains, you can use the domain parameter of [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). However, if they are separate sites, you cannot access the cookie data for the other site. Cookies are **client** side.

Sessions are server side, but the session ID is stored as cookie so you face the same issue. You could read the session data from the PHP session folder, but you'd have no way of knowing which session was for your current user.

Comment: These are different sites with different domainnames. So, how the session understands these are different sites?

Comment: @YouCanDoIt Cookies are stored on a per-domain basis. This is part of the HTTP protocol and can absolutely **not** be changed (for security/privacy reasons). PHP sessions are all stored in a single directory on the server by default, with a randomly generated ID. However, the user's session ID is stored as a cookie. Every time a user goes to the site, the session ID is sent as part of the cookies. This means it is fundamentally impossible to share this data between two sites.